# Populate Spinner from CSV File using Scanner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Using Android (Eclipse) I am trying to read a .csv file and dynamically
populate a Spinner using Scanner. Have tried many methods with the same result.
Emulator shows Spinner but only the last comma and price are populated. Also need to
store all three variables in array and retrive them when Spinner selection is made
in order to populate EditText fields. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...

Data file records:

4,Aluminum Cans,.55   5,Vehicle with cat convertor,9.00   18,Brass ( Irony Red/Yellow ),.20      1001,*Deduction*  Customer # Look-Up,-2.00

Java:

```
public class BRprogramActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //
        Button addButton;
        Button editButton;
        Button sendButton;
        //  
        Spinner array_spinner;
        //
        //      activate soft Keyboard
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
        (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE); 
        //
        //      .csv comma separated values file
        //        
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.brdata));  
            //         
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String data = (scanner.next());
                String [] values = data.split(",");
                item = values[0];              
                description = values[1];
                price = values[2];    
                //  
                array_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);         
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,values);
                array_spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
            }       
            scanner.close();

        }   catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        //
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.v("test", "ADD button clicked");
            }
        });
        //
        editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editbutton);

        editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.v("test", "EDIT button clicked");
            }
        });    
        //
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.v("test", "SEND button clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display each row of your CSV on one row in the spinner, try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    list.add(scanner.next());
}

array_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);         
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
array_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Though has poor readability for the ordinary user, perhaps you only want to display the description and price:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String data = scanner.next();
    String [] values = data.split(",");
    list.add(values[1] + "  $" + values[2]);
}
```

Your posted method only showed the last CSV line, because you were creating a new ArrayAdapter for each line in the CSV and *overriding* the previous adapter that you had created.

By storing the Scanner's results in a List and moving the adapter's definition out of the Scanner loop, you should be able to see results like you had hope.

**Addition from comments**

An OutOfBounds exception with length=2, index=2 suggests that at least one row in your real CSV only has two values (one comma). To help you find that row try this:

```
if(values.length != 3)
    Log.v("Example", "Malformed row: " + data);
else
    list.add(values[1] + "  $" + values[2]);
```

Also, I neglected to mention that you are not setting a drop down layout for your Spinner. This will not cause the app to crash, but this creates the standard user interface:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Modified code as suggested and LogCat shows exception error on array, java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2, index=2.  Sample record s/b   4,Aluminum Cans,.55   .

Comment: also, no data populating Spinner

Comment: Sam, thanks for your excellent help.Spinner populated 3 records out of 50.Looks like a space is terminating all others (ex. 4,Aluminum Cans,.55 ) It breaks into two lines ex. ( 4,Aluminum ) and ( Cans,.55 ) This is a standard file with CR/LF as terminator. Is there a way to override the 'space' in the description ?

Comment: That is weird. Since the other multi-word descriptions don't break into separate lines I would try deleting the character between "Aluminum" & "Cans" in the CSV and replacing it with a space yourself. If that's not an option or otherwise doesn't work, then you could saved the old `values` String in `previousValues` and add a check that if both `values.length == 2 && previousValues.length == 2` then `list.add(previousValues[1] + values[0] + "  $" + values[1]);`

Comment: Sam, sorry I wasn't clear. It was happening to ALL records that had a space in the description. For a test, I replaced all of the 'spaces' with an 'underscore' character. Then ran a "Clean" on the project to recognize the new file. All 50 records populated, scrolled, and selected, and the 1st record was shown as the default. Sure is good to see this after two long weeks. I'll try your latest suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Whoops! I haven't used Scanner myself, so I skimmed the documentation... What happens if you try `scanner.next("\n")` or `final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator")` and `scanner.next(newline)`?

Comment: I remember that a 'formal' csv file uses the comma as a field separator and also encloses each field in "double quotes". This allows commas that are part of a valid description to pass thru. ex. "4", "Aluminum Cans",".55" I'm testing that now. I'll try your latest also. I think the line.separator & line.quote will do the trick for a formal file. Found this odball also, not sure if it works but it does compile: String [] values = data.split(",(?=([^\"]\"[^\"]\")[^\"]$)");

Comment: Are you importing the correct data yet? That regular expression looks like it searches for three pairs of quotes ignoring the need for commas in a CSV, though without running it myself I won't be certain. If you have satisfactory results please close the question by clicking the checkmark in the upper-left corner of this answer.

Comment: Sam, still working with options but your answers have given me most of what I need. I am successfully reading the .csv file (informal comma separator) and populating the Spinner. Have added listeners on the Spinner and Buttons and all is working well. Can't thank you enough for helping here. Hope to talk to you again...