# Populate spinner with data from a CSV file

Tags: java, android, csv, android-spinner

I started Android programming a few weeks ago, and I have now run into a problem.

I am making a LED - Calculator where the user can pick different LEDs in a Spinner. The different LEDs and their corresponding voltage and usage (amps) is listed in a `CSV` file. So when I make the calculations I need to get the data for the LED the user chose.

Basically I need a Spinner with choices from a `CSV` file and a way to get the corresponding data for each choice.

Comment: where did you put the csv file (like assets/raw/ any other place) and what is its content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367790/populate-spinner-from-csv-file-using-scanner .. read your file and for each entry add it to a list, then wrap that list in an ArrayAdapter and set it on your spinner.

Comment: `I am using Android Studio` Irrelevant. @trooper suggestion is good.

Comment: @Sengupta I put it in res/raw. It's a list with some products, with their number, name and some other specifications.

Comment: @trooper Thanks for the suggestion, I will do some research around what you suggested.

Comment: `I put it in res/raw.` Then, it's **not modifiable**. In this case, the easiest way is to use a string array in your arrays.xml file.

Comment: Not modifiable? I have already done this with a Listview, which worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Nothing you put in the raw folder is modifiable. I mean **at run time**, obviously. `res/raw` is read-only, for your app. And so is the `assets` folder.

Comment: I created the folder myself.. I can modify the file itself fine, all I want to do is reading from it. I will be modifying the file directly and update the app rarely.

Comment: Your app will never be able to write into that folder. Nor will do other apps. So, it's not a dynamic thing. I mean, you can't download a file from a server in your res/raw and have the file automatically read without having to recompile your app. And this is really not so useful.

Comment: I don't need my app to write to that folder..

Comment: Then, as I said, the easiest way is to set a string array in your resources.

Comment: I know that is possible, but I am making the app for someone else that doesn't know anything at programming, so a CSV file would be easier for him to modify.

Comment: If he knows how to modify a CSV file, he would have no problem in modifying an xml file. They are both text files.

Comment: I have thought about that, but I am making a LED - Calculator where the user will pick between different LEDs. All of these LEDs have different voltages and usages (amps). How can I associate each LED with their correct voltage and usage (amps) in a string array?

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.

I created a database and imported the data from the CSV file to a table and then found a guide on how to populate a Spinner with data from a SQLite database.

Comment: But this takes 2 steps instead of just one. It's an overkill.

Comment: I know, but there were no answers, so what choice did I have? I couldn't find any guides on this.

Comment: As I told you, using `arrays.xml` is your best choice. Alternatively, you can read the data from the file on the storage into an array and then directly assigning the ArrayAdapter to the Spinner.

Comment: As I told you, that's what I would do. But the guy I'm making this app for has a CSV file with all the products from his online shop so he can just copy paste from that file into the CSV file in the app.

Comment: Since you are going to do everything **manually** (why don't you take the data directly from the remote database, instead?), you can covert the csv file he passes you into an array resource.

Comment: Use your spinner position, if you are getting the values in an ordered way. So that position 0 corresponds to the minimum vale and so on.